# I am unable to fix the ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to write a playbook to create two files .When nested variables are defined. I have got the output but this is not what I expect . I need to create two files with only the variables defines

playbook.yml

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
   variable:
    - name: "item1"
      vars:
        - { id: 1, type: "get" , resource: "Customerid" }
        - { id: 17, type: "post", resource: "Cus" }
    - name: "item2"
      vars:
        - { id: 2, type: "get", resource: "Customerid" }
  tasks:

   - template:
      src: template.j2
      dest: "{{ item.name }}"
     with_items: "{{ variable }}"
```

## template.j2 file content

```
{% for item in variable %}
Item Name: {{ item.name }}
{% for item_var in item.vars %}
{% if item_var['type'] == 'get' %}
    Item ID: {{ item_var['id'] }}
    Item Resource: {{ item_var['resource'] }}
    Get function
{% else %}
    Item ID: {{ item_var['id'] }}
    Item Resource: {{ item_var['resource'] }}
    Post function
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Current result of two files created item1 and item2:

## item1

```
Item Name: item1
    Item ID: 1
    Item Resource: Customerid
    Get function
    Item ID: 17
    Item Resource: Cus
    Post function
Item Name: item2
    Item ID: 2
    Item Resource: Customerid
    Get function
```

## item2

```
Item Name: item1
    Item ID: 1
    Item Resource: Customerid
    Get function
    Item ID: 17
    Item Resource: Cus
    Post function
Item Name: item2
    Item ID: 2
    Item Resource: Customerid
    Get function
```

I would like to get the below output when two files are created . Not sure how to get this. Desired output:

## item1

```
Item Name: item1
    Item ID: 1
    Item Resource: Customerid
    Get function
    Item ID: 17
    Item Resource: Cus
    Post function
```

## item2

```
Item Name: item2
    Item ID: 2
    Item Resource: Customerid
    Get function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the duplicate loop from the template.

```
Item Name: {{ item.name }}
{% for item_var in item.vars %}
{% if item_var['type'] == 'get' %}
    Item ID: {{ item_var['id'] }}
    Item Resource: {{ item_var['resource'] }}
    Get function
{% else %}
    Item ID: {{ item_var['id'] }}
    Item Resource: {{ item_var['resource'] }}
    Post function
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The template might be simplified

```
Item Name: {{ item.name }}
{% for item_var in item.vars %}
    Item ID: {{ item_var.id }}
    Item Resource: {{ item_var.resource }}
    {{ item_var.type|capitalize }} function
{% endfor %}
```